# Python - While loops simple

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am trying to write a function that calculates the number of days a species of bacteria takes for its initial population to reach its final population given that each day its population doubles. My code is;

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
   time = 0
   while initial_population < final_population:
       time+= 1
       initial_population = initial_population * 2
       print(time)
```

This prints each day, but I want it to only print the total number of iterations it takes for the while loop to stop. The output of my code when the function is called with `num_doublings(2, 8)` is

```
1
2
3
```

but I only need it to output 3. How do I fix this ?

Comment: Just move the `print` statement to the left, i.e. out of of the `while` loop.

Comment: If you don't want it to print on each iteration why do you have a print call inside the while loop?

Comment: Why not just use maths? Given a formula `x` to the power `y` is equal or greater than `z`, you have `x` and `z`, so you only need to solve this for `y`.

Comment: You wrote `print` statement inside the loop.thatswhy it print all iteration. Place `print` statement outside the loop and in `scope` of `time` veriable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
    time = 0
    while initial_population <= final_population:
        time+= 1
        initial_population = initial_population * 2

    return time
```

the function will return the time variable which is 3 in the example that you gave

Answer (score 2):

As Martijn Pieters correctly observes, the performant solution is not to use a loop at all:

```
from math import log, ceil

def num_doublings(initial, final):
    return ceil(log(final/initial, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to pull the `print` line outside the while loop. Like so -

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
   time = 1
   while initial_population < final_population:
       time+= 1
       initial_population = initial_population * 2
   print(time)
```

Note that I initialize `time =1`

Answer (score 0):

Is a problem of scope, just print the data when the `while` loop is over:

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
   time = 0
   while initial_population < final_population:
       time+= 1
       initial_population = initial_population * 2
   print(time)
```

Comment: do you get three as the output?

Comment: @ClockSlave, the problem is about the scope where the print function is, either way if you are happier feeling smarter cheating his algorithm you are welcome.

Comment: where does cheating comes in all this? I just pointed out that you won't get `3` as the output. Where does that translate to cheating? Also, I'm not the one who is downvoting everyone. Heck, I got downvoted too.

Comment: @ClockSlave, read the question please, the thing is that he is getting multiple output, not that he cant achive 3 as output.

Comment: So you give a result that answers his question and I simply bring your attention to the point that getting to his answer might need one more tweak and you call out on me for cheating? Choose your words next time.

Comment: @ClockSlave, whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: yeah you too. have fun

Comment: hey dude, sorry about that. I was just pissed when I read `cheating` in your comment and the uninvited demeaning tone it had. But now I realize, its just your opinion. So whatever! Later!

Answer (score -1):

Un-Indent the last line.

```
def num_doublings(initial_population, final_population):
   time = 0
   while initial_population < final_population:
       time+= 1
       initial_population = initial_population * 2
   print(time)
```

Comment: I like the fact that all answers are the exact same, but one of the answering people downvoted all others to push his own answer up. This is why SE is so bad sometimes...

Comment: Also, the upvoted answer is technically wrong, as the question was how to print the variable and not how to return it.

Comment: Except the upvoted answerer doesn't have the reputation to vote down yet. (No, I didn't vote here).

Comment: the answers are probably downvoted as the question could be closed for a typo

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Strange reason for downvoting answers.

Comment: @Gnarf It really is, but it is better for a function to return something than to print it. The caller then can decide what to do with the result.

Comment: @glglgl easier to delete questions with no answers so maybe the downvotes were to try and get the answerers to delete them?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Maybe, but instead of deleting it, it would be better to just close it.

Comment: @glglgl true but anything goes through peoples mind on SO